# htaccess (not the index.php)

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

i am struggling with the .htaccess file. I have got an intro page as the index.php and there is a link. If you click the link, i want that you will get to the home.php. The home.php should be my real(pseudo) main index.php

Here is a pic of my folder structur:

[image]

On that picture you can see my .htaccess file and the folder structur. I am not sure, if the rules are correct.

Thats my index.php:

```
<body onload="main()">
<!-- Main content -->
<div id="main">
    <!-- Logo -->
    <div id="logo">
    </div><!-- End Logo -->
    <!-- h2 Webdesign & Development -->
    <h1 id="text"></h1>
    <!-- End h2 Webdesign & Development -->
    <!-- Enter link -->
    <div id="enter">
        <a href="Home" data-hover="ENTER">ENTER</a>
    </div><!-- End enter link -->
</div><!-- End main content -->
```

There is a "ENTER" Link to the real website(home.php)

Here is my navi.inc.php file:

```
<nav>
<ul>
    <li><a href="Home"><img data-other-src="../pics/home_button_hover.svg" src="../pics/home_button.svg" id="home" alt="Home Button"></a></li>
    <li><a href="Info">Info</a></li>
    <li><a href="Projects">Projects</a></li>
    <li><a href="Contact">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

and finally my home.php:

```
<?php
require_once    '../include/config.inc.php';

if( isset( $_GET['site'] ) ){

$site = $_GET['site'];

}else{

    $site = 'Home';
}

?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Home | <?=$seiten_name?></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../style/main.css">
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Iceland' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/image_switch.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="main">

    <?php

            // Navigation

            switch ( $site ) {

                case 'Home':
                    include('home.php');
                    break;

                case 'Projects':
                    include('projects.php');
                    break;

                case 'Contact':
                    include('contact.php');
                    break;

                default:
                    include('home.php');
                    break;

            }

        ?>

    <div id="preloader">
        <img src="../pics/ajax-loader.gif" alt="Preloader">
    </div>
</div>

<?php

    require('../include/navi.inc.php');

?>

</body>
</html>
```

Sorry for my poor english, but i hope you will understand my problem!! I want the home.php as my index :P

Comment: It is working, I did it right!! But I had a loop inside my switch, therfore my browser was crashing. But thanks for your time :P

Answer (score 2):

Please try below rule in your htaccess

```
DirectoryIndex home.php
```

Comment: where should I paste it in(which place)?

Comment: After the RewriteBase rule

Comment: It is maybe working, but I am somewhere in a loop. I see the body backgroundcolor, but nothing else and my browser is working non stop before he crashes. :D

Answer (score 0):

This is working:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /website/sites/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ home.php?site=$1 [L,QSA]
```